# Mac Remote Desktop - XP32 Crashes on Connect

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, remote-desktop, windows-xp

I'm having an issue where my Windows XP (32-bit) box crashes after I connect using the Mac Remote Desktop Client. The sequence of events is as follows:

1. Connect to XP box using Mac Remote Desktop client: No issues
2. Disconnect RDC session (login remains active on box).
3. Connect to XP box using Win 7 Remote Desktop client: No issues
4. Disconnect RDC session (login remains active on box).
5. **Connect to XP box using Mac client: Boom. Crash. Reboot.**
6. Wait for machine to come back online, GoTo 1.

The reason for using both the Win7 and OSX clients are I use a Windows box at work and a Mac at home. The clients are configured the same. No printers, drives, or applications are loaded and the clients launch in full-screen. Sound is disabled. I tried opening the .dmp files in WinDbg.exe but it was littered with invalid symbols messages (I'm probably using the tool incorrectly). However, RDPDD.dll was mentioned.

Other than that, I'm not sure what's wrong with this box. If I stick with either the Mac or Win 7 client, all is well. Unfortunately, that's not an option. My other machines (XP64 and 2K8 Server) all work fine with both clients.

Any suggestions or tips on how to resolve this or to possibly troubleshoot it further?

Thanks!

Cheers,
Bob

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this same problem, or a similar problem - Windows netbook accessing remote Windows machine with no problems but OS X machine accessing remote Windows machine, will log in, but later crash - and was able to fix the remote machine crashing by making the screen resolution on the OS X RDP client full-screen. Also I'm logged in 32-bit mode on the MacBook Air.